# Not able to debug ProcessBuilder

Tags: java

I need to pass different sh commands using "sudo" and "su" from my java app to linux using java.lang.ProcessBuilder.

These commands are very similar but some work, some don't. When I copy paste the command from the logs, **ALL** command work.

After this one :

```
processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("sudo", "su", "- USER66 -c", "'ssh remote.mycomp.org < " + workingDir + "/script_cluster.sh'");
```

I have :

```
su : option invalide -- ' '
Usage: (...)
```

But this one :

```
processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("sudo", "su",  "- USER66 -c", "'scp remote.mycomp.org:" + clusterWorkingDir + "/" + filename + " " + workingDir + "/resultat/" + dir + "/'");
```

works perfectly.

And like I said earlier, if I copy the first command from my logs, it 
works without any warning.

logging code :

```
  logCommand(processBuilder);

  private void logCommand(ProcessBuilder processBuilder) {
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
      logger.debug("Commande : {}", commandAsString(processBuilder.command()));
    }
  }

  private String commandAsString(List<String> command) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (String cmdElement : command) {
      result.append(cmdElement).append(" ");
    }
    return result.toString();
  }
```

What am I missing here ? What else can I do to understand what is going on ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found a surprising way to solve to this problem :

The trick was not to split the arguments but instead to regroup them using "bash -c" :

```
processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-c", "sudo su - USER66 -c 'ssh remote.mycomp.org < " + workingDir + "/script_cluster.sh'");
```

notice how unintuitive this is because nobody would write it like this in a shell, and it could become quite hard to translate it in a shell command with the proper nested escape. Also if you concatenate the 3 pieces of command with spaces, it does not form a valid command.

Answer (score 0):

The ProcessBuilder constructor requires a separated string for each argument. In your code several arguments are combined in one string. Try this one:

```
new ProcessBuilder( "sudo", "su", "-", "USER66", "-c", "'ssh remote.mycomp.org < /script_cluster.sh'");
```

(It should be correct to treat the value for the -c flag as one argument.)

**Explanation**

Most of the native system methods to create a new process require each argument as a separated element of an array (e.g. take a look at the [execve](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) documentation).

During runtime, Java will encode the arguments to one continues byte array, before passing it to the native JVM method, which will call the native system method. For example `"su", "-", "USER66", "-c", "'...'"` will be decoded as `su-USER66-c'...'`. The individual arguments are separated by a 0 byte (which we don't see in the string). The native JVM method decodes the continues string by splitting the string by the 0 byte delimiter. If we `"su - USER66"` as one argument, it will be wrongly encoded as *one* argument for the native system method.

When you call the command from a shell or bash, the arguments are also split to an array, before they are passed to the underline native system method.

Comment: I think this hypothesis ignores the fact that my second command with "- USER66 -c" works fine.